# mysql returns value even on string input whereas the column contains integer values on equal in where clause

Tags: mysql

trying to run the below procedure. works fine but i don't understand why it is returning values if i pass string values for int column.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`abdal`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 

`sp_select_car_detail_multiple_search`(IN `car_detail_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `maker_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `model_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `y_from` YEAR(4), IN `y_to` YEAR(4), IN `cc_from` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `cc_to` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `fuel` VARCHAR(50), IN `start_row` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `end_row` INT(11) UNSIGNED)
    NO SQL
SELECT * FROM `car_detail` c

LEFT JOIN `dd_maker` m
ON
m.`dd_maker_id` = c.`dd_maker_id`
LEFT JOIN `dd_model` a
ON
a.`dd_model_id` = c.`dd_model_id`
LEFT JOIN `dd_vehicle_type` v
ON v.`dd_vehicle_type_id`=c.vehicle_type

WHERE
(
    (car_detail_id = '' OR c.`car_detail_id` = car_detail_id)
    AND
    (maker_id='' OR c.`dd_maker_id` = maker_id)
    AND
    (model_id='' OR c.`dd_model_id` = model_id)
    AND
    ((y_from='' OR y_to='') OR c.`manufacture_year` BETWEEN y_from AND y_to)
    AND
    ((cc_from='' OR cc_to='') OR c.`cc` BETWEEN cc_from AND cc_to)
     AND
    (fuel='' OR c.`fuel_type` = fuel)
)

ORDER BY c.car_detail_id DESC
LIMIT start_row,end_row
```

Comment: MySQL automatically converts between strings and numbers when necessary.

Comment: Where in the  code are you passing strings?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: @Barmar for car_detail_id

Comment: `car_detail_id` is `INT(11)`, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your help

Comment: BTW, it's confusing to use variables that are the same as table columns. It's easy to get confused about whether it will access the variable or column (I had to look it up to see which is preferred).

Comment: yes i know but for e.g if i give input string instead of int it returns the record whereas it shouldn't. i checked the documentation and the problem is solved with CONCAT(); thank you for your guidence

Comment: it dosen't matter it works fine even i put same variable as column names

Comment: I know it works, it's just poor coding style.

Comment: :D ok i will keep this in mind sir. thank you.